# Compute integral closure using a computer

Tags: computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose given an inclusion $A\subset B$ of finitely-presented commutative algebras over a field. Is there a CAS which can decide whether $B$ is a finite $A$-module?

What if instead of f.p. k-algebras, I have an extension of DVRs ([discrete valuation rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring))?

Alternatively, is there a CAS that can compute the integral closure of a dvr or f.p. k-algebra in a finite separable extension of its field of fractions?

Comment: Are you assuming the algebras to be commutative?

Comment: Yes I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macaulay2 has the method [isModuleFinite](https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/PushForward/html/_is__Module__Finite_lp__Ring__Map_rp.html).

Magma has a function [IntegralClosure](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/468#4857), but it seems to only work over function fields. Macaulay2 allow you to [normalize certain integral domains in their fields of fractions](https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/IntegralClosure/html/_integral__Closure_lp__Ring_cm__Ring_rp.html), but Magma allows you to take the integral closure in an extension of the field of fractions.